# How can I do a contour plot with date and time in the x-y axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some data that looks like this:

```
#date       time        temp    press    rh
09/10/2011 07:50        11.4    798.1   14.1
09/10/2011 08:00        11.9    798.3   13.6
...
09/10/2011 11:30        FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
09/10/2011 11:40        25.4    798.3   11.2
09/10/2011 11:50        23.2    799.1   11.2
.....
```

I want to do a contour plot of "temp" with the "time" in the x-axis and "date" in the y-axis.

I tried using Pandas to handle the dates and the `NaN` values better.

```
data=np.genfromtxt("dataFile.txt", comments="#", dtype='str')

header_names=['date', 'time', 'temp', 'press', 'rh']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=None, columns=header_names) 
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date   
df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%H:%M').dt.time
df.temp = pd.to_numeric(df.temp, errors='coerse')
....

dfMesh=df.pivot('date', 'time', 'temp')
X=dfMesh.columns.values
Y=dfMesh.index.values
Z=dfMesh.values

x,y=np.meshgrid(X, Y)
plt.contourf(x, y, Z)
```

But I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "./contourPlot_pandas.py", line 33, in 
>         x,y=np.meshgrid(X, Y)
>         File "/Users/marybau/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py",
>   line 4533, in meshgrid
>           return [x * mult_fact for x in output]
>         File "/Users/marybau/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py",
>   line 4533, in 
>           return [x * mult_fact for x in output]
>       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'datetime.time' and 'int

'

I have also tried different other ways to do it without using pandas, but I end up with similar problems due to the `date-time` format or the `NaN`. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

matplotlib `contour` needs to convert the X and Y values to floats, based on a little reading around where I get error messages. Contour plotting is complicated enough that restating the date-time to plot well with the existing function is probably easier than extending `contour`.

Convert the date and time values to numbers that will be spaced out correctly; for instance, dates as Julian date integers, and times as minutes-since-midnight.  Starting with making dummy data and then re-formatting it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from math import pi, sin

ts = pd.date_range('1/1/2017 0:00', '1/24/2017 23:00', freq='H') # 24 * 24 long
temp = map(lambda x: sin(2*pi*x/40), range(576))  
# tiny testcase: sin(2*pi*x/12) or /24 provide horizontal contours: quite right.


df = pd.DataFrame({'date':map(lambda x:int(x.to_julian_date()), ts),
                   'time':map(lambda x:x.time().hour*60 + x.time().minute, ts),
                   'temp':temp})

dfMesh = df.pivot('time','date','temp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

conts = ax.contour(dfMesh.columns.values, dfMesh.index.values, dfMesh.values)
ax.set_xlabel('Julian day')
ax.set_ylabel('Minutes since midnight')

plt.show()
```

[image]

That will do for investigating your data as a diurnal contour plot.

To make the plot labels more understandable, you can edit the existing ticklabels, or change the places the ticks are put and give the new ticks the date- or time-string labels. But those are questions handled elsewhere on SE, as are contour plotting with missing values, interpolating, etc.